# Obstacle with Ruby Rails Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a brand new Ruby on Rails User

When I enter localhost:3000 ,

I get an error reading

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
You have 2 pending migrations:
20221119205559_add_devise_to_users.rb
20221119211811_drop_users_table.rb
```

```
# Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
      def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
        raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
      end

      def load_schema_if_pending!
```

In a nutshell, it was working before but I attempted to create a a basic authentication page(which was also working) , but for some reason when I clicked sign up I received an error also.

Thank you for any tips on how to fix this!

I have tried to

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate

Editing the migrate file with: 

 edit your migration file

class DropUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users
  end
end

Then doing rake db:migrate
```

Also, I have run :

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Did you run the migration as the error instructs?

Comment: Some installations via the `generate` command create migrations you *must* run before Rails will be fully operational because they depend on important database schema changes to work.

Comment: run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` again and try restarting your server.  is any of it displaying an error message?